# Sharepoint Online - Implement REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Is is possible to implement **REST WebApi** in Sharepoint Online environment?

This question comes from the need to integrate an external website with a Sharepoint Online site.

The external website should be able to send data to Sharepoint Online throug an exposed method of REST API.

Is it possible to do it in Sharepoint Online ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but given your question (showing lack of REST knowledge), I can tell you are going to have a hard time getting it to work, search for ADAL & SharePoint

Comment: What exactly need to do is send JsonData from a Wordpress website to Sharepoint Online in order to fill a List. Thats it. I think that REST APIs are the only way...

Comment: No it isn't. Search for something like PHP PDO CSOM, a guy called Vadem Gremnachek (or something like that) wrote all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

Library to make WordPress (PHP) write to a SharePoint List

https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

It does it with REST, but you don't have to do it yourself